# GdiplusStartup fails with GenericError when called from within splwow64 but not others

Tags: windows, gdi+, gdi

I have this situation where a dll is injected into processes that are printing to monitor the print jobs, i wanted to use a few GDIplus apis to help with image transformation within the dll being injected.

When the dll is injected into regular 64 bit processes the code works well. But when a 32 bit process prints, windows launches splwow64.exe as expected and we inject into it, but in this context, Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup returns a status of GenericError.
From the doc that just eliminates, all the other errors but doesn't help in any other way.

Can anyone help decode or point in the direction to debug this situation?

Comment: are splwow64 run in interactive session ? not in 0 session (i not check) ? in anycase - for what you need UI in splwow64 ?

Comment: its not a UI, i want to convert a bitmap that i have obtained in the process(from the print) to png file using GDI+.

Comment: i ask about sessionid of splwow64 and for convert bitmap to png you not need gdiplus. you can use IWICImagingFactory and related interfaces

Comment: session id same as interactive process 1.

Comment: in this case can not just say why, without debugging, but in any case use IWICImagingFactory for this task more corect and will be work